# Why redeclaring a variable is allowed in an IF statement in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, var

I know an `if` statement doesnt have its own scope like a function, meaning it shares the same scope than the containing context. But if so, why Im allowed to redeclare the same variable again?

```
var foo = 123;
if (true) {
    console.log(foo) // 123
    var foo = 456; // Shouldnt it throw an error if refers to same variable?
}
console.log(foo) // 456
```

Comment: No, since they have different scopes (global vs local). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#Initialization_of_several_variables.

Comment: both are hoisted and recognized as same.

Comment: @NinaScholz Understood everything with your simple and concised answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: one of the many pitfalls of using `var` - `let` or `const` would throw an error here, but `var` hoists both to the same declaration

Comment: This looks like a good question for me by seeing the output of the console logs, if it is scoped, I was expecting undefined for the first log and 123 for the second, good question.

Comment: @Tick20 that is not how scopes work, a lower scope (like the if statement) has access to all variables from the higher scope, so the first log should indeed log `123`

Comment: @Klaycon, you are right, since it is the same variable, it should work the way it is working now according to Nina's and Your explanation.

Comment: `var` does have scope, it's just that it's functional scope.  The reason no error appart from spec, is maybe down to not accidentally creating a global.  And the advantage of it been this way it saves you having to declare all vars at the top of the function.

Comment: @Keith tricky to call that an "advantage" - this behavior of `var` leads more often to programmers attempting to declare and use a local variable in a lower scope, and then accidentally the variable is hoisted with another one in higher scope and they modify that one instead - hence why it's bad practice to use `var` that way (or at all)

Comment: @klaycon Yes, but `var` is old, the advantage was then not now.  Now using const and let is best practise.

Comment: or just declare all variables at top.

Comment: or declare all variables where they're needed, only with `let` to avoid easily caught mistakes!

Comment: @NinaScholz you should create an answer from your comment, since it answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

We need to understand how the compiler and the Javascript runtime engine process and executes the code.

## Compiler

lets see how the compiler sees the below code snippet and creates appropriate scopes.

```
1. var foo = 123;
2. if (true) {
3.   console.log(foo) // 123
4.   var foo = 456;
5. }
6. console.log(foo) // 456
```

1. on Line 1 compiler places `foo` identifier in global scope as it encounters that identifier for the first time.
2. on Line 2 it compiler creates a block scope to hold the references of identifiers.
3. on Line 3 is a execution context so, compiler moves to next line.
4. on Line 4 compiler sees `foo` identifier and it checks whether the identifier already exist in the global scope or not (  Note: `var` does not has the block scope. So it looks one level up in the scope, which is global scope). Here global scope already had the identifier so, it goes to next line of code.
5. Line 6 is a execution context.

## Javascript(JS) engine

It assigns and executes the code by using the scope created by the compiler.

1. Line 1 runtime looks for the identifier `foo` in the scope, as it exist it assigns the value `123`
2. Line 2 is truthy So, it enters into the block.
3. on Line 3 it looks for the identifier `foo` in the block scope. As `foo` does not exist in the block scope it looks one level above which is global scope. `foo` is available in the global scope with a value of `123`. so `console.log(foo)` is `123`
4. on Line 4: it looks for the identifier `foo` in the block scope. As `foo` does not exist in the block scope it looks one level above which is global scope. `foo` is available in the global scope so it re-assigns the value `456` to `foo`. now `foo is 456`.
5. on Line 6. JS engine looks for `foo` identifier in the current scope which is global scope. `foo` is available in the global scope with a value of `456`.

Now, let see the question

#### Why redeclaring a variable is allowed in an IF statement in JavaScript?

`var foo = 456;` is looks like redeclaring but actually it's not doing that. it uses the same globally declared identifier.

In some cases it's good to doing this kind of pattern for **`readability`** purpose.

```
function test() {
  var siteId;
   
  if(condition) {
    // more code 100+ lines
    siteId = getId();
  } else {
    var siteId = 1001; // redeclaring here we are communicating the reader for sure we have the `siteId`
  }
   
 // other code

}
```